# Find a GameObject and check if the user has clicked on it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently been making the UI for a game I am creating and have run into a problem.
I have been trying to find a way in the new Unity 4.6 for the user to be able to click on a player card and have it select the player they clicked on.

```
public void Panel1Click()
{
    GameManager.Player1Select ();
}
```

This is the way I am doing it at the moment, calling this when the player clicks on Panel 1, there are also 3 more for each of them.

I have been researching different methods on how to find the object the player clicks the execute the correct selecting code.

```
if (GameObject.Find ("Panel 1")) 
{
    print ("Click Panel 1");
    GameManager.Player1Select();
}
```

This is one of the methods I tried, however nothing gets called. (Because it just checks if the object exists/is true? I think).

All these methods are linked to the `EventSystem` component on the panels.

Is there a more efficient way of condensing all the functions and just checking which panel the player clicks on?

Comment: Did you read the button tutorials? Unity 4.6 can call any function you want when it is clicked? I am not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah I did, I am trying to use one function to for all the panels Then when the player clicks on one of the panels the code checks which one is clicked on and executes the right piece of code. I will look over the button tutorials again, just in case I missed something, thanks for the response!

Comment: You can't click on a GameObject. Instead, you can click on a GUI element, or a physics collider, which could be added as a component to a GameObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a collider to the game object (sprite), and then in the **OnMouseDown** function to test if it is clicked.

Select the card --> Add a box collider to it --> Add a MonoBehaviour script and attach to the card --> In the script, add function:

```
 bool bClicked = false;
 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " is clicked");        
     bClicked = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have one parameter for your click handler. Supported types are: `int`, `float`, `string` and `object reference`. So you can define your handler like this:

```
public void SelectCharacter(int character) {
    GameManager.PlayerSelect(character)
}
```

Then just set the parameter in the event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script and put it on the object(Panel) you want to interact with, then try this code. In this example it finds the parent panel and sets it to inactive

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CloseInventory : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    GameObject inventoryPanel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        inventoryPanel = GameObject.Find("Inventory Panel");
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //SET WHAT TO DO HERE
        inventoryPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```